# How to count the longest number of W and longest number of L consecutively in a column?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a sheet that shows my games played, I want to be able to see my longest win streak and longest loss streak. How can I count the longest streak?

I tried =IF(C2="W",T1+1,0) and =MAX(Games!T:T)

This works but not very effectively as I add a new row every time I play a game so the formula has #REF errors sometimes as it doesn't like being referenced to itself. Also I would prefer to not have to add a new column just to get the counting.

[Here is a link to the sheet if you would like to look and see what I mean.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FkY--tMtM8mJ0BIdRi7c2kY7TUWBic1Bg_AI1KQU3WQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can't you do it like ```=SORTN(FREQUENCY((B2:B="W")*ROW(B2:B)``` to get the longest win streak?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SCAN to make a cummulative count:

```
=VSTACK("Wins",
SCAN(0,C2:C,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v="W",a+1,0))))
```

[image]

I used VSTACK to put the formula in the Header

If you don't actually need the column you can just use MAX and the SCAN:

=MAX(SCAN(0,C2:C,LAMBDA(a,v,IF(v="W",a+1,0))))

Do the same with the Losses ;)
[image]